# Reloading CSS on not my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make some kind of toolbar in JS as GreaseMonkey script and I need high contrast options. They are already implemented on few pages but I'm going to apply them to any website I'm visiting.
I have buttons that apply high contrast and they work kinda good but I don't know how to resume default CSS. Every solution I found is good when used on my own page when I know DOM tree structure, classes, ids etc. but as I said, it's supposed to work on any page.

What I use to make contrast is:

```
    var OA_whiteBlack_f = function(){
    $("*").not("video").not("object").not("embed").css("cssText", "background: #000 !important; color: #fff !important;");
    };
```

As you can see I added some .not to avoid changing players (what still doesn't work on youtube)

Any ideas how I can restore stylesheet computet on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with returning your style is if there is any existing inline style on any of those elements you would need to store it first which you can do using `data()`

Note that `cssText` wipes out any existing inline style which may present problems in some pages

```
var $elements = $("*").not("video,object,embed").each(function () {
    var $el = $(this),
        currStyle = $el.attr('style') || '';
    $el.data('stored_style', currStyle ).css("cssText", "background: #000 !important; color: #fff !important;");
});
```

To undo ... loop over all the elements and replace style attribute with stored value

```
$elements.each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.attr('style', $el.data('stored_style'));
});
```